# QGIS problem exporting to both SVG and PDF

Tags: qgis, pdf, svg, illustrator

I'm having a problem when exporting to SVG and PDF from qGIS. When I open the SVG or PDF in Illustrator, the path of my map is severely cut off with lots of data missing (see below).

When I open the PDF in Acrobat, it looks fine. So this is a problem with how Illustrator is handling the files.

I've tried simplifying the geometry and can't get it down below ~70,000 vertices. I've also tried splitting the object in two but then the exported SVG is completely blank.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for geometry errors, like duplicate nodes?

Comment: @AndreJ, I ran Check Geometry Validity and it returned no errors/duplicate nodes.

Comment: Illustrator has vertices limit of 32,000 http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=9794 so you will have to generalise even more.

Comment: Thank you! I had to play around with the simplify tolerance but I did get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Illustrator has an undocumented ceiling limit on the maximum number of vertices you can have in a single segment of a line/polygon. This limit is **32,000 vertices** in one line segment.

There are some ways around this limit.

Make the polygon a line, the break the line up into smaller lines or use a generalise tool.
You can rebuild the polygon in Illustrator from line work you will not lose to much detail as illustrator can use arcs for curves.

Another option is to break/split the polygons into smaller polygons before exporting (you can group these back in illustrator) to make a single polygon.

http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=3093